# Bike & Speed problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A biker covers a straight road distance of 30 km in 20 minutes when he is riding in the direction of the wind. He covers the same distance in 40 minutes when he is riding in the direction opposite to the wind. How fast can he cover the distance if there is no wind blowing?

Comment: Have you done any work on the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: How do I calculate the speed of the bike not able understand?

Comment: let $x$ be the speed of biker with no wind and $y$ is the speed of the wind. Can you write two equations for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Okay x = 3/2 (Speed of wind) & y = 3/4 (Opp direction of wind). But how will I get the actual speed of the bike?

Comment: $(x+y)/3=30$ (30 km in 20 min)

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider

$x=$ rate of rider in still wind

$w=$rate of wind

$t=$time

$d=$distance in $\frac{km}{hr}$

With wind $=x+w$, $t=\frac13$, $\ d=30$

Against wind $=x-w$, $t=\frac23,$ $\ d=30$

$$\frac13(x+w)=30$$ and $$\frac23(x-w)=30$$

$$x+w=90,x-w=45$$
$$2x=135$$
$$x=\frac{135}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint.

Let $v$ be the speed of the biker without the wind, and let $w$ be the speed of the wind.

The assumption is that the wind adds (or subtracts) from his net speed.

Speed is distance over time.

So, one equation will be

$$v+w = d/t_{fast}$$

where $t_{fast}$ is the time it takes when the wind is helping him.

There's a similar equation that involves $t_{slow}$.

From there, you can eliminate $w$ and solve for $v$.

Your turn. ;)